# Use geom_vline to plot ticks in xaxis and color gradient it

Tags: r, ggplot2

Sample data

```
SNP_BP  LD
13203   1.00
13456   0.74
13646   0.43
...     ....
```

And using ggplot to make the ticks.

So far I have tried using the following command:

```
p <- ggplot()+
geom_vline(data=d, mapping=aes(xintercept=SNP_BP))+
scale_x_continuous(limits=c(12345,14533)
```

Now when I try that it says:

> Error in exists(name, envir = env, mode = mode) :   argument "env" is missing, with no default

Also, I need to add to this plot the colour gradient for those ticks (based on its LD (column) value).

Comment: `scale_x_continuous(limits=c(12345,14533))`

Comment: I think that  the problem is that ggplot has no information about the y axis. So you should either add points or lines (e.g. `+geom_point(aes(x=SNP_BP,y=LD))`) from which ggplot can get the y-axis range or you specify the y-axis range explicitly, e.g. by `+ scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1))`. What exactly do you mean by your last statement about the colour gradient? Do you want to colour the lines based on `LD`?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.. i will try that now.. and about the colour lines yes would like it graded in colours based on its LD value..

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that ggplot has no information about the y axis and can therefore not create the plot. This can be solved by explicitly stating limits for the y-axis with `scale_y_continuous`:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
ggplot(d) +
   geom_vline(aes(xintercept=SNP_BP,colour=LD)) +
   scale_x_continuous(limits=c(12345,14533)) +
   scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1)) +
   scale_colour_gradientn(colours=brewer.pal(7,"YlOrRd"))
```

As soon as you add points or lines (or something else) to the plot, ggplot will determine the y-axis range from the range covered by these points and there will be no need for `scale_y_continuous` any longer.

I also added colours for the lines by setting the aesthetic `colour=LD`. Adding `scale_colour_gradientn(...)` is optional and I only put it to show you a possibility, how you can change the colours. I use colours from the package `RColourBrewer` (with `brewer.pal()`), which I find very useful.

Using the three data points that you give in your post, the code leads to the following plot:

[image]